# Android URL and HttpURLConnection Exception when trying to get data from a server

Tags: android

I'm trying to get data - just a json string for testing - and invoking the connection in some android activity from a thread like you see in the code :

```
package eng.hasan.medico;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class RegisterNewUser implements Runnable {

    String innerName;
    String innerEmail;
    String innerMobile;
    String innerPass;
    String innerBirthDate;
    int innerGender;
    RegisterNewUser(String name ,String email ,String mobile ,String pass ,String birthDate ,int gender){
        innerName = name;
        innerEmail = email;
        innerMobile = mobile;
        innerPass = pass;
        innerBirthDate = birthDate;
        innerGender = gender;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HttpURLConnection connection;
        BufferedReader reader;
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(Globals.site + "index.php/General/reg_new_user" );
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                //Handle Error getting Data
            } else {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
                if(jsonData.getBoolean("success")){
                    Globals.registerGlobalObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Globals.registerGlobalObject.hideProgressBar();
                            Globals.registerGlobalObject.notifyRegSuccess();
                        }
                    });
                }else {
                    Globals.registerGlobalObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Globals.registerGlobalObject.hideProgressBar();
                            Toast.makeText(Globals.registerGlobalObject ,"حدث خطأ في تسجيل البيانات" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }catch (final IOException e){
            Globals.registerGlobalObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Globals.registerGlobalObject.hideProgressBar();
                    Toast.makeText(Globals.registerGlobalObject ,"خطأ في الشبكة" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e("Error medico" ,e.getLocalizedMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Globals.registerGlobalObject.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Globals.registerGlobalObject.hideProgressBar();
                    Toast.makeText(Globals.registerGlobalObject ,"خطأ في البيانات" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

But the code throws an IOException : Here is the log and StackTrace :

```
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 5068-5068/eng.hasan.medico W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.10.97/medico/index.php/General/reg_new_user/
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 4565-4742/? D/ConnectivityService: mDiagnosticHisotry, str: UNBLOCKED 10127
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 4565-4742/? D/ConnectivityService: mDiagnosticHisotry, str: UNBLOCKED 10193
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 4565-4742/? D/ConnectivityService: mDiagnosticHisotry, str: UNBLOCKED 10220
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 5068-5068/eng.hasan.medico W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:255)
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 5068-5068/eng.hasan.medico W/System.err:     at eng.hasan.medico.RegisterNewUser.run(RegisterNewUser.java:44)
2019-10-31 15:58:58.874 5068-5068/eng.hasan.medico W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
2019-10-31 15:58:58.875 4565-4590/? W/libprocessgroup: kill(-7542, 9) failed: No such process
```

This is the line that caused the ecxeption :

```
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

The code works with other activities very well (ie. I copied and pasted it with makking necessary changes)
Any suggestions ,with my respect .

Comment: http://192.168.10.97/ seems to point to a localhost ip, is this wrong, or are you hosting the server on your local machine?

Comment: Yes I'm hosting my site that gives the data on a machine that is on the same local network with the android device .and the other connections (from other activities in the app.) work properly

Comment: https://localtunnel.github.io/www/ check out this one for exposing local host so you can connect from device or emulators.

Comment: I told you I have the same code working on other Runnable java files threaded by another activities .

Comment: Any suggestions guys ??????